# A Tough Problem about Residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I tried my best to solve this problem from what I learned in residues, but the solution seems very far from what I was doing!!
Is there any way other than using Laurent series expansion?
 Here is the problem:
$$f(z)=(ze^{2-z}+(2-z)e^z)e^{(z-1)^{2}+(z-1)^{-2}}  $$ at z = 1

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

Write $z:=1+t$ with $t$ near $0$, and look at the resulting expression: It is an *even* function of $t$ in a punctured neighborhood of $t=0$.

Comment: It becomes [(t+1)e^(1-t)+(1-t)e^(t+1)]e^{(t^4+1)/t^2}. Its limit as t goes to zero is infinity, right? What does it mean? t=0 is a pole of f(t)? Also, near t=0, the left factor of the product goes to 2e, and the right factor goes to infinity.