# A Question About Poles.

Tags: singularity-theory

I have some questions in my mind bothering me to understand poles.

Let  $z_0$ be a pole of order $m$ for $f(z)$. Does that mean:

1- $(m+1)$ is the smallest positive integer such that: $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)(z-z_0)^{m+1}=0$ ?

2- For any  $n <m$, we have:  $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)(z-z_0)^n=+\infty$ ?

3- Could we have $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}f(z)(z-z_0)^m=0$?

Comment: This looks a bit like homework. =)

Comment: I swear it is not :(

Comment: 1yes,2yes,3no.  $f$ looks like $\sum_{n=-m}^{\infty}a_{n}(z-z_0)^n$ with $a_{-m}\neq0$ in a nbhd of $z_0$

Comment: What else can be said of $f$?

Comment: @ Dr. MV I am not sure. Do you mean $limf(z) = infinity , as  z-> z_0$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

We can write $f(z)=\dfrac{h(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}$, in a neighborhood of $z_0$, where $h$ is an analytic function.  Then, we have

$$h(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{h^{(n)}(z_0)(z-z_0)^n}{n!}$$

and therefore

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{h^{(n)}(z_0)(z-z_0)^{n-m}}{n!}$$

Comment: You're welcome!  My true pleasure helping you.

Comment: @ Dr. MV Thank you so much Dr MV. If you have time please look at this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391435/a-tough-problem-about-residue